# Error al leer y guardar en un array 10 números enteros en Java

Tags: java, array, matriz

Cuando ejecuto el código este, me da error. No sé si será la longitud del array o si será el `for`. Lo que tengo que hacer es leer 10 números y ordenarlos en dos array, uno de pares y otro de impares.

Les comparto mi código:

```
        int pares [] = new int [10];
        int impares [] = new int [10];
        int numeros [] = new int [10];
        int length = 0;
        int contPares=0, contImpares=0;
        
        for(int a=0; a<=9; a++){
            numeros [a]= Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba su número"));
            
            if(numeros [a] % 2 == 0){
                pares[contPares] = numeros[a];
                contPares++; 
             }else{
               impares[contImpares] = numeros[a];
               contImpares++;
             }
        }
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los números pares son:\n "+pares [0]+"\n"+pares [1]+"\n"+pares [2]+"\n"+pares [3]+"\n"+pares [4]+"\n"+pares [5]+"\n"+pares [6]+"\n"+pares [7]+"\n"+pares [8]+"\n"+pares [9]+"\n"+pares [10], "Pares", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los números impares son:\n "+impares [0]+"\n"+impares [1]+"\n"+impares [2]+"\n"+impares [3]+"\n"+impares [4]+"\n"+impares [5]+"\n"+impares [6]+"\n"+impares [7]+"\n"+impares [8]+"\n"+impares [9]+"\n"+impares [10], "Impares", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta al guardar el arreglo, realice una implementación simple en base a tu código para que puedas guiarte, espero te sea de utilidad:

```
    int tamañoMaximo = 10;
    int pares [] = new int [tamañoMaximo];
    int impares [] = new int [tamañoMaximo];
    int contadorPares = 0;
    int contadorImpares = 0;
    int numeroLeido;
    String cadena = "";
    
    for(int a=0; a<tamañoMaximo; a++){
        numeroLeido = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Escriba su número"));
        if(numeroLeido % 2 == 0){
            pares[contadorPares++] = numeroLeido;
        }else{
            impares[contadorImpares++] = numeroLeido;
        }
    }
    
    cadena = "Los números pares son:\n";
    for(int i=0;i<contadorPares;i++)
    {
        cadena += pares[i] + "\n";
    }
    cadena += "Los números impares son:\n";
    for(int i=0;i<contadorImpares;i++)
    {
        cadena += impares[i] + "\n";
    }
    
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, cadena, "Numeros", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 1):

No estas asignando ninguno de los valores a tus arrays resultado(pares/impares). Te recomiendo que utilices dos contadores uno por el array de pares y otro por el de impares e ir incrementándolos a medida que vayas llenando dicho array. Tal que así:

```
if(numeros [a] % 2 == 0){
    pares[contPares] = numeros[a];
    contPares++; 
}else{
    impares[contImpares] = numeros[a];
    contImpares++;
}
```

Luego para mostrar los valores del array ten cuidado porque vas a mostrar posiciones vacías ya que solo tienes 10 números y estas printado 20 los 10 del array de pares y otros 10 para los impares. Pon atención a la hora de mostrar esta información. Igual puedes hacer-lo con un bucle y concatenar los resultados en un String.

Comment: Gracias! Pero tendría que cambiar el primer for(int a=0; a<=9; a++) por for(int contPares=0; a<=9; a++)?

Comment: Me sale este error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 10 out of bounds for length 10
 at matrices.Ejercicio9.main(Ejercicio9.java:41)